# Linux - stopping kernel module from automatically loading

Tags: linux, boot, kernel-module

I am using Angstrom distribution on my Overo board, and I have a little problem. Sometimes kernel modules that are used to handle my camera are loaded at boot time, sometimes not.

I am wondering, is there some file where there are modules listed that should be loaded at boot time? Or is there some other way that the system *knows* what modules to load?

Anyway, I wanted to make Linux don't load those modules automatically so I always know that I need to load them up manually.

Also I wanted to disable automatic loading of a module that is used for wireless because it takes few seconds for this module to set up and most of the time I am not using wireless net on my board.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are searching the "blacklist" function. From [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_modules#Blacklisting):

> Blacklisting, in the context of kernel modules, is a mechanism to
>   prevent the kernel module from loading. This could be useful if, for
>   example, the associated hardware is not needed, or if loading that
>   module causes problems: for instance there may be two kernel modules
>   that try to control the same piece of hardware, and loading them
>   together would result in a conflict.
>
> [...]
>
> Create a .conf file inside /etc/modprobe.d/ and append a line for each
>   module you want to blacklist, using the blacklist keyword. If for
>   example you want to prevent the pcspkr module from loading:

```
> /etc/modprobe.d/nobeep.conf
> 
> # Do not load the pcspkr module on boot 
> blacklist pcspkr
```

Comment: I searched the net, it seems that Angstrom has a different way of handling those things. In etc I have `modules`,`modules.conf` files and `modutils` directory.

Comment: Ok, i googled the manpage of modules.conf. please try "alias <MODULE-NAME> off" in /etc/modules.conf